# NLTK RegexpParser Stanford tagger issues with handling dates where its a mix of numbers and letters

Tags: python, regex, date, nltk, pos-tagger

I'm wondering if its possible to corretly tag dates in a text documents where they can be in either `DD/MM/YYYY` or `DDth Month YYYY`.

My regex pattern is;

```
from nltk import regex_tokenize
from nltk.tag import StandfordPOSTagger
text = 'The date the world ends is 12/12/2012 or for the more intellectual 12th December 2012'
sentence_re = r'''(?x)(?:(?:[A-Z])(?:\.[A-Z])+\.?)
                | (?:[£$]?\d+(?:.\d+)*%?)
                | (?:\w+(?:-\w+)*)
                | (?:\.{3}|[][.,;\"\'?():_`-])'''

toks = nltk.regexp_tokenize(text, sentence_re)
st = StanfordPOSTagger('Path/to/stanford-postagger-full-2015-12-09/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger'
                       ,'Path/to/stanford-postagger-full-2015-12-09/stanford-postagger.jar' )

stand_tok = st.tag(toks)

for j, k in stand_tok:
    if k == 'CD':
        print j,k
```

only returns `(12/12/2012, CD)` and `(12,CD), (2012,CD)` instead of `(12/12/2012, CD)` and `(12th December 2012, CD)`;

is there a solution or approach that would get the desired outcome without replacing all instances of `th` and `Month` with the numerical equivalent and work for any sized `text` input.

Comment: That will be a tedious pattern like https://regex101.com/r/RZmPTf/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I will gladly take tedious over nothing any day, I'm not sure If I'm going crazy here but when I run the code with the new regex it only outputs 12/12/2012 and 2012 whilst the toks is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/OOPWY1. Regex tokenizer should work the same, but I admit I can't test it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this "(\d\d/\d\d/\d{4})|(\d\d\w\w\s\w+\s\d{4})" could work.
It uses the or operator '|' and matches either "dd\dd\dddd" where d is any digit, or it matches "ddww word dddd" where d is a digit and w is a word character (a-zA-Z). it does this by using `\d` to match digits `\d{4}` to match 4 digits, `\s` to match spaces `\/` to match `/` and `\w+` to match any number of word characters.

Here it is in a JavaScript example.

```js
 var value = "12/23/1444 12th September 2016 12adkj 3ghkd fkghadk g 35mbadg da 13/56/45 492305612/45/67575757";
var matches = value.match(
     new RegExp("(\\d\\d\\/\\d\\d\\/\\d{4})|(\\d\\d\\w\\w\\s\\w+\\s\\d{4})", "g")
);
document.writeln(matches);
```

As you may notice it matches even if there is no space before it, you can use \b which matches boundary if you want a regex that only matches dates when they are separate from other text, like this `\b(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})\b|\b(\d\d\w\w\s\w+\s\d{4})\b`. Here it is in action.

```js
 var value = "12/23/1444 12th September 2016 12adkj 3ghkd fkghadk g 35mbadg da 13/56/45 492305612/45/67575757";
var matches = value.match(
     new RegExp("\\b(\\d\\d\\/\\d\\d\\/\\d{4})\\b|\\b(\\d\\d\\w\\w\\s\\w+\\s\\d{4})\\b", "g")
);
document.writeln(matches);
```

I hope this helps, please note if you want to restrict the length of the word that represents the month you can use \w{n,n1} instead of \w+ this will give you n to n1 word characters or you can use \w{n} to get exactly n characters.